# How to limit number of records in TFDMemTable?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a **TFDMemTable** filled with thousands of records. Is there a way to limit result records for only the first 50 ?

I've tried to use:

```
FDMemTable.FetchOptions.RecsSkip := 0;
FDMemTable.FetchOptions.RecsMax := 50;
FDMemTable.Open;
```

But it did not work, data remained unchanged.

Comment: Yes, there is :) No time right now. Sorry.

Comment: @Victoria, could it be that your last name is Fermat by any chance?

Comment: @Uwe, no, no :) Silva is my surname.

Comment: @Victoria:  I would have guessed Shirunova.

Comment: @MartynA, why? Who is Victoria Shirunova? Never heard of :)

Comment: @Victoria:  Viktoria S actually.  I was guessing, starting from the list in the Alt-Team Easter Egg under Delphi | About.

Comment: @MartynA, aha, no, no. I never worked directly for EMBT :)

Comment: @Victoria:  Well, that's their loss ...

Comment: @Wel, you changed the topic to _How to limit number of records..._, does it mean you want to just filter out certain ones from the current view (but they remain saved in the physical storage)?

Comment: @Victoria I just felt it better describe what I need like SQL limit.

Comment: @Wel, if you want to keep records stored in the internal storage and only limit current view, write a filter, e.g. [a range filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Filtering_Records_(FireDAC)#Filtering_by_Range_of_Values). I understood your question as that you want to delete the records physically from the memory table.

Comment: @Victoria I dont have a field I can use for filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect @Victoria will be able to show you a better and more general
way, but there are at least two ways to do this:

- Use FD's FDLocalSQL feature to copy the first X rows of the FDMemTable into, say,
  an FDQuery and then copy them back into your FDMemTable.
- Apply a filter to the FDMemTable to filter out the other records, use an FDBatchMove
  to copy the X records into a second FDMemTable and then copy them back into the original
  FDMemTable.

To implement the first of these, add the following components to your form/datamodule:

```
FDLocalSQL1: TFDLocalSQL;
FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
```

and then execute code like this:

```
procedure TForm3.CopyData1;
begin
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;

  FDLocalSQL1.Connection := FDConnection1;
  FDLocalSQL1.DataSets.Add(FDMemTable1);  // this is the source dataset

  FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;

  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from FDMemTable1 order by ID limit 5';  //  ID being an Integer field of the FDMemTable
  FDQuery1.Active := True;

  FDMemTable1.Close;
  FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;  // Re-opens FDMemTable 1, which now contains only the first X records
end;
```

FD's LocalSQL uses Sqlite to do its stuff. The functional equivalent in Sqlite's SQL
to "Select Top X ..." is its limit clause.

An advantage of using LocalSQL for your task, of course, is that because LocalSQL
supports order by, you can it to determine which (top) X records are retained.

The batchmove method requires a bit less code but requires you to have a way of identifying
the first X records using a filter expression.  An example using an ID field might be

```
procedure TForm3.CopyData2;
begin
  FDMemTable1.Filter := 'ID <=50';
  FDMemTable1.Filtered := True;
  FDBatchMove1.Execute;  //  move data from FDMemTable1 to FDMemTable2;
  FDMemTable1.Close;
  FDMemTable1.Data := FDMemTable2.Data;  // Re-opens FDMemTable 1, which now contains only the first X records
end;
```

Btw, you say

> I have a TFDMemTable filled with thousands of records. I

I think the problem with the method you've tried is probably that by the time you have the records in the FDMemTable, it's too late to try and limit the number of them in the way you're attempting. *)

Comment: I was thinking of removing tuples from the internal storage with final `Resync`. You can even see similar inside the `EmptyDataSet` method. Pretty easy to just modify for range deletion instead of clearing. Btw. local SQL supports `DELETE`, so one should be able to delete only certain tuples (without copying).

Comment: But copying and dropping the whole source dataset might be more efficient.